# Check whether a number is positive, negative, or zero

Tags: python, beginner

I have a program which generates a number between 0 and 4 for both the player and the computer.  If the number is positive the player wins, and if it is negative the computer wins.

```
if dif == 1 or dif == 2 or dif == 3 or dif == 4:
    print 'Player wins!'
elif dif == -1 or dif == -2 or dif == -3 or dif == -4:
    print 'Computer wins!'    
else:
    print 'Player and computer tie!'
```

How can I make the `if` and `elif` statments simpler?

Comment: Now that you have a review, do not post your entire code as that will invalidate the answer (regardless of my previous comment).

Answer (score 7):

We should use the comparison operators.  Greater than, less than.

```
if dif > 0:
    print 'Player wins!'
elif dif < 0:
    print 'Computer wins!'
else:
    print 'Player and computer tie!'
```

Another option, which I'm led to believe is "more Pythonic" (although, I'm not a Python dev, so don't take my word for it...), looks like this:

```
def tie():
    print 'Player and computer tie!'

def player():
    print 'Player wins!'

def computer():
    print 'Computer wins!'

options = {
     0 : tie,
     1 : player,
     2 : player,
     3 : player,
     4 : player,
    -1 : computer,
    -2 : computer,
    -3 : computer,
    -4 : computer
}

options[dif]()
```

If explicit values are important, than this solution is probably good.  However, if you really only care whether a value is greater than, less than, or equal to a specific value, than a simple `if`/`elif`/`else` as I first demonstrated is a good option.

Note that this bottom option will run into a KeyError if `dif` is not in the range of expected values.  The `if`/`elif`/`else` will work for any number.

Comment: `options = { -1: computer, 0: tie, 1: player } , 
options[cmp(player_score, computer_score)]()`

Comment: Although the lookup table in the second solution is simple to read, the mechanism that interprets it is a bit of magic; for this reason alone I would say it is actually a good example of _non_-Pythonic code! I agree with your first solution; it could be made even clearer by ditching the `dif` thing altogether and comparing the player’s and computer’s scores to each other directly. This would make the code more similar to how a person reasons about the scores, and consequentially more Pythonic, if you like.